# Some posts from custom post type to subdomains

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomains

I have custom post type where all posts associated with some persons.

**Like:** `mysite.com/masters/master-name/`

And i need to have redirection from `master-name.mysite.com`. 
This redirection will be created automatically.

Comment: I don't think this is strictly WordPress-related as it deals more with Apache and mod_rewrite.